# Eliminating the linear term in a cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. It is known that by substituting $$x=t-\frac{b}{3a}$$ we get a depressed cubic, which does not have a quadratic term.

My question is: Is there a substitution that will remove the linear term instead?

Comment: under the rational transform $x = \frac{t}{1-\frac{ct}{3d}}$, the numerator will be a cubic polynomial w/o the $t$ term.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take $x=y+k$, $k\in\mathbb{R}$, replace in the equation and find $k$ so that the linear term vanishes.

Comment: for some cubic equation, e.g. $x^3 + x + 1$, $k$ need to be complex to get rid of the linear term.