# Every number field of degree $3$ is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I want to show that every number field of degree $3$ is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of the form $m_\alpha(x) = x^3 + ax + b$.

Let $K$ be the cubic number field. By the primitive element theorem, we know $K = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ where $m_\beta(x) = x^3 + c_2x^2 + c_1x + c_0$. But I don't know how we can pick $\beta$ such that $c_2 = 0$.

Hints would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you make a substitution, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609684/eliminating-the-linear-term-in-a-cubic)?

Comment: With a quadratic - to illustrate $x^2+2ax+b=(x+a)^2+b-a^2$ and set $y=x+a$. Now can you do the same thing in your example?