# Characterization of cubic fields over Q

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I ran across the following characterization of cubic fields over $\mathbb{Q}$:

If $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$, then $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of the form $X^3+aX+b$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Where can I find a proof of this? More importantly, what are some known generalizations of this, for example does this also hold for all fields with characteristic not equal to some small primes like $2$ and $3$?

Is there a similar characterization of quartic fields?

Comment: By the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#:~:text=In%20field%20theory%2C%20the%20primitive,simple%20extension%20in%20this%20case.), every extension $K/\Bbb Q$ of degree $n$ is of the form $\Bbb Q(a)$.

Comment: Yes, but does this say anything about the form of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$? For example, in the case $n=3$ I don't need the square term. Is there a similar canonical form for quartic fields?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432663/every-number-field-of-degree-3-is-of-the-form-mathbbq-alpha-where-alp). It is the same question.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that post.